# How to sum of specific column data by specific month of MS Access and get to textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Can't get sum of columns value with specific month wise.

I was trying to get data from MS Access to textbox or label, but there only blank result.

```
    Dim Month As String = dtInput.Value.ToString("MMM")
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim str As String = ""
    str = "Select Sum(Input_Amount) FROM Input_Paid Where Month(Dt_Entry)='" & Month & "'"

    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    dbconnect1()

    rs.Open(str, conne, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)

    lblInputtotalInputDeposite.Text = "Total Deposit Input this Month - " & rs.Fields(0).Value
    rs.Close()
    rs = Nothing
```

I except the output is not blank there came some result here:

```
(rs.Fields(0).Value)
```

Comment: It different, you compare abbriviated month name with number of month

Answer (score 0):

Never use literals for month filtering as these are localised:

```vb
Dim Month As Integer = dtInput.Value.Month()
Dim Year As Integer = dtInput.Value.Year()

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim str As String = ""

str = "Select Sum(Input_Amount) FROM Input_Paid Where Year(Dt_Entry) = " & Year & " And Month(Dt_Entry) = " & Month & ""

dbconnect1()
rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open(str, conne, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, DODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockPessimistic)
lblInputtotalInputDeposite.Text = "Total Deposite Input on this Month - " & rs.Fields(0).Value

rs.Close()
rs = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, lets do it the ADO.net way.

Keep your database objects local so you can control there opening, closing and disposing. The later two are accomplished with the Using...End Using blocks.

To get help on connection strings see https://www.connectionstrings.com/

It is a good idea to use parameters to avoid sql injection. Access does not care about parameter names. If only cares that the order they appear in the command text matches the order that they are added to the parameters collection.

ExecuteScalar returns the first column of the first row in the result set. In this case, the sum. It returns an object so needs to be converted to a decimal.

Only after the connection is closed, we update the user interface. I used an interpolated string.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Total As Decimal
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Sum(Input_Amount) FROM Input_Paid Where Month(Dt_Entry)= @Month And Year(Dt_Entry) = @Year;", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", OleDbType.Integer).Value = dtInput.Value.Month
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", OleDbType.Integer).Value = dtInput.Value.Year
            cn.Open()
            Total = CDec(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using 'closes and disposes the connection
    lblInputtotalInputDeposite.Text = $"Total Deposit Input this Month is {Total}"
End Sub
```